# Possible to get the "New viewers" and "Total Unique viewers" breakdown by country, channelID, videoID

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am checking the ability to fetch YT data through the Youtube analytics API. I am using Google AppScript "[YouTube Analytics Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/youtube-analytics#:%7E:text=The%20YouTube%20Analytics%20service%20allows,must%20be%20enabled%20before%20use.)" to fetch data. Here is the [dimensions](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/dimensions) and [metrics](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/metrics) document I found.

I was told that using YT Analytics API will allow us to obtain raw datasets which will allow us to track new/existing viewer statistics even if the video asset is shared by multiple geographies. However, I can not see there is any support for "New viewers" and "Total Unique viewers" in the documents. The report I would like to have
Dimensions: "New viewers" and "Total Unique viewers" breakdown by Metrics: "country", "channelID", "channelName", "videoID", "videoName"

If you have any experience with it, please share your thought with me
Bests,